# filter condition except specified row given row index number dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
name count ... 
a    9
b    10
cc   5
d    6
e    2
f    14
...
```

I am trying to filter the rows with a count value greater than 8 except the rows "d" and "e" despite them being less than 8.
To filter this condition, I would usually start with `df %>% filter(value > 8)`, but I'm stuck on where to add the special condition of keeping the rows with name = d and e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = c('a', 'b', 'cc', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 
                 count = c(9, 10, 5, 6, 2, 14)
)

df %>% filter(count > 8 | name %in% c('e', 'd'))
```